# How to change Web Api Core unauthorized behavior

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-3

The default `ASP.NET Web Api Core` behaviour for unauthorized request is to send `401/403 error` with empty content. I'd like to change it by specifying some kind of Json response specifying the error.

But I struggle to find a right place where I can introduce these changes. Official documentation is of no help (read it all). I had a guess that may be I could catch `UnathorizedException` in my exception filter / middleware but it didn't work out (I guess it gets handled at authorization level or even not thrown at all).

So my question is how can I customize response behavior in case of unauthorized request.

Comment: Check out extension methods like `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects` and `app.UseStatusCodePages`

Comment: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie` go to this... it may help

Comment: @Developer, it seems to be specific to MVC, not Web Api

Comment: Is there such a distinction in asp.net-core? What is your auth mechanism?

Comment: @Developer, I use token authentication. Here' the code by the way: https://github.com/alexidsa/absenceapi

Comment: Still I kind feel `app.useStatusCodePages` might work, havent tried so not sure. - `app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
{
    context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(
        "{Status code page, status code: " + 
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode+"}");
});` -- or navigate ro some action and send your response

Comment: @SiberianGuy have you solved it? I'm migrating my web api to Asp.Net Core and get same issue now.

Answer (score 0):

With .Net Core 3 (or may be earlier as well) you can write a middleware to check if the context.Response has a status of 40x and then return a custom object. Below is roughly how I did it:

```
if (context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
{
 var result = new MyStandardApiResponseDto
 {
  Error = new MyErrorDto
   {
    Title = "Unauthorized",
     Messages = new List<string> { "You are not authorized to access the resource. Please login again." },
   },
  Result = null
 };
 await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
}
```